# Scroll to bottom of ScrollView in React Native

Tags: react-native

I would like to find a way to programmatically scroll to the bottom of a scrollView. I am aware of the scrollTo method after looking at the source code for ScrollView, however I cannot seem to find a way to measure the content size of the scrollView.

After looking around, I came across [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/913) github issue that mentions to look at how "UIManager.measureX methods are used" to measure content size. However after searching several times through the source code, I cannot quite seem to find where these methods are used.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was pretty consealed and I ran into the source code.

You can try like this:

require:

```js
var RCTUIManager = require('NativeModules').UIManager;
```

render:

```js
<ScrollView ref = {component=>{this._scrollView=component;}}>
</ScrollView>
```

event:

```js
someEvent: function() {
  RCTUIManager.measure(this._scrollView.getInnerViewNode(), (...data)=>{console.log(data)});
}
```

From the data, you can get the contentsize of the scrollview whose height is the fourth element of `data`. Of course you can get the content offset from it. Run into the source code of `RCTUIMananger.m` for more details.

When you use `getInnerViewNode` you can get the frame of ScrollView's inner view's frame. If you want to get the ScrollView's frame, you should use `React.findNodeHandle(this._scrollView)`, and ScrollView's frame is not always equals to its inner view's frame.

---

(updated)

If you want to replace `(...data)=>{console.log(data)}` with `callback`, you should use it like this:

```js
RCTUIManager.measure(this._scrollView.getInnerViewNode(), callback.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried what you said, however the data parameter always comes back as 0 (zero), rather than an object (or array). Any ideas?
I think I've found the source code you are talking about (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTUIManager.m). The first parameter of measure seems to be a reactTag but I'm not entirely sure what that tag refers to.

Comment: @coldbuffet Sorry, forget the `...`. I had updated my answer. Use `(...data)` instead.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, now I am able to receive the scollView content size height, however there seems to be another problem. Any time I refer to 'this' inside of the callback for RCTUIManager.measure, I get a null error. This happens whether I call this._scrollView or this.someOtherMethod. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where is your callback? Had you added the `ref` to the ScrollView?

Comment: Yes ref has been added to scroll view as I am getting the correct scrollview content height. The callback looks like this:
RCTUIManager.measure(this._scrollView.getInnerViewNode(), (...data)=>{
console.log(data);
this._scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0); //error here
});

However after playing around for a little bit, I found that doing:
RCTUIManager.measure(this._scrollView.getInnerViewNode(), this.someMethodUsingThisKeyword);

doesnt throw an null error. My guess is that when using the anonymous function I dont have a reference to 'this'? Could you explain this behaviour?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: It's ok for me to use `this` in the `(...data)={}`. I updated my answer. Try to use `bind(this)` to a `callback`.

Comment: Did you use `callback` like `var callback = ...`?

Comment: I didnt use the callback like that. I will investigate the issue deeper and see what it is..cheers KChen

Answer (score 3):

Yo can use **scrollToEnd()** method of the ScrollView:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrolltoend

According to the documentation:
*If this is a vertical ScrollView scrolls to the bottom. If this is a horizontal ScrollView scrolls to the right.*

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way to do this. In broad strokes:

Use a [ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) to render the chat.

```js
<ListView
  ref="list"
  ...
```

Add a footer to the list with [renderFooter](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderfooter) that uses [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) to save its `y` position. The footer doesn't have to render anything visible, just an empty `View`. All you're looking for is where the bottom of the list is.

```js
renderFooter={() => {
  return <View onLayout={(e)=> {
    this.footerY = e.nativeEvent.layout.y;
  }}/>
}},
```

Add an `onLayout` handler to the `ListView` itself that saves the lists `height`.

```js
onLayout={(e)=>{
  this.listHeight = e.nativeEvent.layout.height;
}}
```

With those two bits of information you can scroll to the bottom of the list with something like:

```js
if (this.listHeight && this.footerY && this.footerY > this.listHeight) {
  var scrollDistance = this.listHeight - this.footerY;
  var scrollResponder = this.refs.list.getScrollResponder();
  scrollResponder.scrollWithoutAnimationTo(-scrollDistance);
}
```

How often you scroll to the bottom is up to you and depends on the behavior you want.

An example of this in action is [GiftedMessenger](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-messenger/blob/master/GiftedMessenger.js).

Answer (score 1):

While `RCTUIManager.measure()` does work by extracting the 4th element of the data array via reference, it's much more appropriate ( and easier ) to use the following when working with ScrollViews:

RE: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#oncontentsizechange

```
onContentSizeChange={( contentWidth, contentHeight ) => {
    this._contentHeight = contentHeight
}}
```

This event will fire once the inner child components finish laying out and upon change.  This works for me and I recommend this supported approach when determining content bounds.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollView ref={scrollView => this.scrollView = scrollView}
      onContentSizeChange={( contentWidth, contentHeight ) => {
        this._contentHeight = contentHeight;
        console.log('Height: ' + this._contentHeight);
        this.scrollView.scrollTo({ y: this._contentHeight , animated: true})
    }}>
```